# Drawing shapes on FlowDocument

Tags: flowdocument

I have an application for viewing reports on flowdocument. I have been able to show text file on flow document scroll viewer, now i want to draw various shapes like ellipse, rectangle, circle etc. over my flow document content. Iam using Canvas over my flow document to get things done but no success has been found yet.

Kindly help how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I happen to come across the same requirement recently and have done some research.

Basically, there is no way of doing that as FlowDocument generates mouse events only from hyperlinks or buttons - images, canvases and other suitable for your request controls don't generate these events.

I haven't found anything about it on MSDN but [this comment](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3229948/Why-doesnt-Microsoft-support-the-documented-mouse-.aspx) confirms my point.

I suppose, therefore, you'd have to create your own paginating and scrolling control and render your report pages into it.

Hope it helps.